# Pandas to Excel: Using loc[] to access a value in the Excel for calculation does not work unless the index is repeated

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Trying to modify values on an Excel by using Pandas.
Screenshot of current Excel:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg0Mb.png

When trying to modify values in the last row, I want to access values of its different columns using a combination of loc[] and iloc[]. However, it does not work. I do not understand why can't I access the value, as it only works when a value is repeated in the index. For example, if TSLA was twice in the Excel. Apparently, loc[] does not let me look for a value.

tradeStopLoss = 5

def sellWriter(tradeStopLoss):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pytz
import numpy as np
now = dt.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
ExcelPD = pd.read_excel(r"xxx.xlsx")
ExcelPD.set_index('TICKER', inplace=True)

TICKER = 'TSLA'
DIAYHORAVENTA = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
PRECIOVENTA = 5466
RETORNO = round((PRECIOVENTA - (ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['BUY PRICE'])
/ ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['BUY PRICE']),2)
MULTIPLORIESGO = round((RETORNO / ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['RISK']),2)
PROFITORLOSS = (PRECIOVENTA - ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['BUY PRICE'])\
            * ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['QUANTITY']

idx = np.arange(ExcelPD.shape[0])[ExcelPD.index == TICKER][-1]
col1 = ExcelPD.columns.get_loc('SELL DATE')
col2 = ExcelPD.columns.get_loc('SELL PRICE')
col3 = ExcelPD.columns.get_loc('RETURN')
col4 = ExcelPD.columns.get_loc('RISK MULTIPLE')
col5 = ExcelPD.columns.get_loc('P/L')

ExcelPD.iloc[idx, col1] = DIAYHORAVENTA
ExcelPD.iloc[idx, col2] = PRECIOVENTA
ExcelPD.iloc[idx, col3] = RETORNO
ExcelPD.iloc[idx, col4] = MULTIPLORIESGO
ExcelPD.iloc[idx, col5] = PROFITORLOSS

ExcelPD.to_excel(r"xxx.xlsx")
```

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xxxx", line 92, in 
sellWriter(tradeStopLoss)
File "xxxxx", line 67, in sellWriter
RETORNO = round((PRECIOVENTA - (ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['BUY PRICE'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: Here `ExcelPD.loc[TICKER].iloc[-1].loc['BUY PRICE']`, you have three `.loc/.iloc` in a row - while you can have only two, because the table is two-dimentional (it has only rows and columns, no third dimension for the third `.loc`). So Python tries to apply the third `.loc` to the content of the cell, and complains about it.

Comment: Just tried what you mentioned @Alex, still getting the same mistake. Output below: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxx", line 92, in <module>
    sellWriter(tradeStopLoss)
  File "xxxx", line 67, in sellWriter
    RETORNO = round((PRECIOVENTA - (ExcelPD.loc[TICKER, 'BUY PRICE'].iloc[-1])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'